# Disable MobaXterm file browser sidebar from opening automatically

Tags: ssh, terminal, mobaxterm

This seems like a simple question but I can't find an answer. I use MobaXterm free edition to SSH into my machines. Every time I SSH into a machine the side bar automatically expands with the paths on the remote machine. I don't need this side bar and every time I have to collapse it. Is there a way to permanently disable the side bar or at least not automatically expend it when SSH-ing?

Here is a picture (linked) of the expaned sidebar:

[image: mobaxterm_sidebar]

Answer (score 75):

Under settings there are these 2 settings that control this that I typically turn off.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. I knew it had to be something obvious that I was just missing.

Comment: Looks like in newer versions these options have been renamed to _"Enable graphical SSH-browser"_ and _"Automatically switch to SSH-browser tab after login"_, but they work the same way.

Comment: Excelente answer, thank you so much, it fixed my issue also :)

Answer (score 6):

In newer versions of MobaXterm (v21.3 as of this writing), as an alternative to adjusting `MobaXterm.ini` file as mentioned in the other answer, it could be disabled by changing ***Session settings  Advanced SSH settings  SSH-browser type*** from ***SFTP Protocol  None***

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This deactivates the annoying SSH-Browser popup. This also works in versions of MobaXterm (v11 in my case).

Answer (score 4):

While instructing users through the GUI settings is an option it is often desirable to implement the application with an already usable default configuration. These settings are stored in the MobaXterm.ini file.

Hints for locating this file can be found here: [Mobaxterm configuration settings](https://blog.mobatek.net/post/mobaxterm-configuration-settings/)

I'm using windows and mine was in my Documents/Mobaxterm folder

Here are the configuration settings I use to remove the sidebar and set the app to compact mode:

```
[WindowPos_xxxxxxxxxxxxx]
...
CompactMode=0
SidebarVisible=0
...

[SSH]
...
AutoStartSSHGUI=0
EnableSFTP=0
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to fix the issue. and with the below fix, the default browser in the MobaXterm can be disabled for all types of sessions including WSL, etc.

Please find attached screenshots below,  just 2 tickboxes need to be disabled

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]